# Angular +2 doesn't add cookie with proper way i can see that it added some cookies and the other cookies didn't added successfully

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to add cookie then redirect to another page and return again and see the cookie exist but this didn't happened i don't know why 
i'm using angular +2 can any one help me out to solve it ?

Comment: Could you please provide what you've got so far ? Maybe add information about the errors you are getting, the article you looked at before posting here. What you tried and didn't work. All those things will help us understand what you are trying to do and how to help you.

Comment: i'm trying to add cookie and redirect to another page then the page will redirect me back to my side then i need to check the cookie but the cookie disappeared i don't know why

Comment: This does not give us any information on how you are setting and retrieving the cookie.

Comment: this is the code of setting cookie 

`public setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 3600 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=http://example.com";
  }`